# Contract throws Invalid address when using send() function in solidity 0.4.6

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

This is the solidity code that I am trying. Compiling of the code works fine. However, when I call the function send() via javascript it throws exception : throw new Error('invalid address');

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6; 
contract Agreement {
   address owner;
   address seller; 
   uint amount; 

   function Agreement(address _seller,uint _amount) {
     owner = msg.sender; seller=_seller; amount=_amount;
   } 

   function send(){
    if (owner.balance < amount) throw;      
    if (seller.balance + amount < seller.balance) throw;
    if(!seller.send(amount))throw;
    } 
}
```

This is the javascript code

```
var compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(contractRaw);
var contract = web3.eth.contract(compiled.info.abiDefinition);
var nContract = contract.new('0x61e323dcf5e116597d96558a91601f94b1f80396',web3.toWei(10, "ether"),{from:this.web3.eth.coinbase, data: compiled.code, gas: 380000}, function(e, contractDetails){
        if(!e) {

            if(!contractDetails.address) {
                console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contractDetails.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

            } else {
                console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contractDetails.address);
                console.log(contractDetails.send())

            }

        }
    });
```

Whenever the code runs, it throws invalid address error and crashes.

Comment: Have u tried to replace this.web3.eth.coinbase from a harcoded value from one of your accounts that appear in console?. Could be that this.web3.eth.coinbase is empty or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

That address in fact exists ([etherscan link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x61e323dcf5e116597d96558a91601f94b1f80396)) > , but it's not a contract address. If was, must open [like this](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x525D67eF6a08Ad80C0956Ca04Af7eB2Cd02A8BF0).

When you deploy your contract to etherium, you must copy the hash resulted on contract creation (transaction hash) and search for it on etherscan. It will open all transaction details, including the created contract hash. **Use that hash.**

Answer (score -1):

Try `61e323dcf5e116597d96558a91601f94b1f80396`, without the `0x`